# Given a set of lines/corners (shown), determine largest quadrilateral?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, convex-hull

Given something as follows (points are known for corners, equations are known for lines), how can I determine the largest/outermost quadrilateral/set of lines/set of corners?

I'm stumped. The closest thing I've come across is a convex hull, but this will create a list of more than 4 corners.

Thanks!

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the solution would be to first generate a list of lines that are parallel to each other (should get at least two sets of lines) based on grouping them by 3D slope. You then go through the sets of lines to find sets of parallel lines that are in the same plane. You should then be able to extract the quadrilateral(s).